# How do you remove undefined keys from a hash?

Tags: perl, hash, dictionary, key

Trying to use map and grep to figure this out, any idea whats wrong? I keep getting a 
**Can't use string ("10") as a HASH ref while "strict refs"** error when I try to print the values of the new hash

```
sub scrub_hash{
    my($self,$hash_ref) = @_;
    my $scrubbed_hash = map { defined $hash_ref->{$_} ? ($_ => $hash_ref->{$_}) : () } keys %{$hash_ref};   
    print STDERR "[scrub]". $_."\n"  for values %{$scrubbed_hash};
}
```

used here 
...

```
my $params_hash = $cgi->Vars();
my $scrubbed = $self->scrub_empty_params($params_hash) if $self->is_hash($params_hash);
```

in this case the params that are undefined when a form is submitted via post still show up as key1=&key2= so scrub takes em off

Comment: Also: `delete @hash{ grep !defined($hash{$_}), keys %hash };`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this line here:

```
my $scrubbed_hash = map { defined $hash_ref->{$_} ? ($_ => $hash_ref->{$_}) : () } keys %{$hash_ref};
```

You are assigning a list from `map` into the scalar `$scrubbed_hash`.  `map` in scalar context will return the number of elements in the list (10).

Rather than assigning to a scalar, assign to a plural hash:

```
sub scrub_hash{
    my($self,$hash_ref) = @_;
    my %scrubbed_hash = map { defined $hash_ref->{$_} ? ($_ => $hash_ref->{$_}) : () } keys %{$hash_ref};   
    print STDERR "[scrub]". $_."\n"  for values %scrubbed_hash;
}
```

If you really wanted to use a scalar for `$scrubbed_hash` you will need to wrap the map statement with `{map {...} args}` which will construct an anonymous hash out of the list.

To filter out the elements in place, you could use the `delete` function:

```
my %hash = (foo => 1, bar => undef, baz => 2);

defined $hash{$_} or delete $hash{$_} for keys %hash;

print join ', ' => keys %hash;  # foo, baz
```

---

per the update:

The `scrub_empty_params` method should look something like this:

```
sub scrub_empty_params {
    my ($self, $hash) = @_;
    {map {defined $$hash{$_} ? ($_ => $$hash{$_}) : ()} keys %$hash}
}
```

If that is not working for you, then it may be that your values are defined, but have a length of 0.

```
sub scrub_empty_params {
    my ($self, $hash) = @_;
    {map {(defined $$hash{$_} and length $$hash{$_}) ? ($_ => $$hash{$_}) : ()} keys %$hash}
}
```

You might want to remove a bit of boiler plate from your API by creating a different `->Vars()` method that returns a filtered hash:

```
sub clean_vars {
    my ($self) = @_;
    $self->scrub_empty_params($self->Vars)
}
```

Comment: the part for keys %hash -- thats just a clever for loop -- is map just another way to write a for loop or is it a faster way to do the same thing?

Comment: for/foreach and map are fairly similar.  The big difference is if you are trying to build a list with the loop.  If so, `my @list = map {...} @src` is shorter and clearer than `my @list; push @list, ... for @src`.  If you are only using the looping aspect, using `for` or `foreach` states your intention more clearly, and will be a little faster.

Comment: In particular, the `foreach` construct understands that `1 .. 10000` is a range, and will not create all the numbers before the loop starts.  Whereas `map {...} 1 .. 10000` has to build all of the numbers in the range before starting the loop.  In other words, `for`/`foreach` has more optimized cases than `map` does.

Comment: thanks for clarifying that the former example doesnt work, when I return %scrubbed_hash it has all the keys in it still =/

Comment: @nodebunny => you will need to post an update to your question with the new code that you are having a problem with.  Please include how you are calling `scrub_hash` as well.

Comment: also did you mean : defined $hash_ref->{$_} or delete $hash_ref->{$_} for keys %{$hash_ref}; in the second example?

Comment: The code in my example used hashes instead of references, but your comment shows a correct conversion to reference usage.  The other popular way would be `defined $$hash_ref{$_} or delete $$hash_ref{$_} for keys %$hash_ref` which would be how I would have written it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    my %scrubbed_hash = map { $_ => $hash_ref->{ $_ } } grep { defined $hash_ref->{$_} } keys %{$hash_ref};
```